# Вызвать resolve для анонимного промиса через стороннюю функцию

Tags: javascript

Имеется такая конструкция:

```
function doSmth() {
    resolve("aga");
};

new Promise(resolve => doSmth())
.then(result => console.log(result));
```

Которая не работает.
Вполне логично, что контекст теряется, поэтому я пробовал `call`:

```
new Promise(resolve => doSmth.call(this))
```

Всё равно не работает. Не видно функцию `resolve()` внутри функции `doSmth()`.
Ну и вопрос: это вообще реально? И если да, то как?
А может я просто с конструкцией как-то не так поступил, не как нужно?

UPD:

Добавлением `this.` перед `resolve` в функции `doSmth` удалось решить проблему с потерей контекста. Теперь `resolve` виден в это функции. Правда... `resolve` в ней почему-то не функция. Это просто undefined. И я не понимаю - почему...

```
function doSmth() {
    this.resolve("aga");
};

new Promise(resolve => doSmth.call(this))
.then(result => {console.log(result)});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`resolve` - это параметр, а не свойство непосредственно Promise. Поэтому контекст тут ни причем.

Чтобы замкнуть этот параметр нужно объявлять функцию непосредственно внутри конструктора, либо наоборот сделать *doSmth* этим конструктором:

```
function doSmth(resolve) {
    resolve("aga");
};

new Promise(doSmth)
```

либо просто передать этот параметр напрямую:

```
function doSmth(resolve) {
    resolve("aga");
};

new Promise(resolve => {
    // какой-то код
    doSmth(resolve);
})
```

Comment: Ага, понятно теперь. Всё понятно, кроме того, чтo resolve - это параметр. Что это значит, я не понимаю? Почему не функция?

Comment: @VostokSisters, это значит, что функция Promise принимает в качестве аргумента функцию с двумя параметрами, которую потом вызывает, передавая ей в качестве параметров две функции resolve и reject

Comment: Это значит, что замкнуть не получится? Потому что по сути это не замыкание, ведь контекст никак не передается, а функция `doSmth()`просто участвует в конструкторе (в первом случае) или функция-параметр `resolve()` передается в качестве аргумента к `doSmth()` (во втором случае).